# How do you find out which ParserElements are matching strings in Pyparsing?

Tags: python, parsing, debugging, exception, pyparsing

I have a complex of sub-ParserElements anded together like so, and I plan on adding more.

```
Group(multi_line ^ macro_parser ^ numeric_assignment ^ assert_parser ^ db ^
                                  charmap_parser ^ comment_parser ^
                                  include_parser ^ label ^ expression ^ macro_call ^
                                  newcharmap_parser ^ popc ^ pushc ^ redef ^ control ^ Literal("\n"))
```

I am running into problems where one of these of the sub-ParserElements will match when it is not supposed to, and I will get a ParseException that does not tell me which ParserElement raised it. This means I have to go around looking for which of the expressions is matching which lines and it takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to get more helpful info when exceptions are raised? I have tried appending .setDebug() to the parser above, but the error message isn't any more helpful.

Comment: You'll need to add `.setDebug()` to each of the expressions in the Group. There is no need to parse `Literal("\n")` pyparsing will implicitly skip whitespace. Lastly, '^' can be a much more expensive (as in "slow") operator than '|', since '^' returns pyparsing Or, which evaluates all expressions and then picks the longest match. '|' returns MatchFirst, which will only parse as far as the first match and then return that. You'll get some other tips in the pyparsing wiki (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki) and the docs (https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Calling `setName()` on the sub expressions will also make your debug output easier to follow.  (This looks pretty complex, have you written a BNF? Strongly recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

The useful things, to help your end-user to understand their own parse failures from using your parser logic, would be to enhance the error output of your own ParserElements by using:

- `.setName()` Python method
- to be selectively using the PyParsing/Python `-` operator, instead of `+` operator.

## `.setName()`

`.setName()` allows you ***re***-state your parse error output (in plain 8th-grade “English” sentence, or a simplest BNF, or even an mnemonic),  Although I’ve often used a multi-line EBNF text surrounded by a pair of triple (`"""`).

The default of `.setName()`, that you defined to a ParserElement at Python assignment-time … to that Python variable, is to show a string in textualized form of its entire “PyParsing-ese” logic used therewithin, which is often of a little help to the average users.

Whenever end-user experiences a `ParseExceptions` that occured within that variable, the new simpler `.setName()` text of that PyParsing variable will be shown instead.

## Using Minus Symbol Selectively

Replacing SOME `+` with `-` can help your end-users (and you) to get closer to a “more correct” location offset of that offending character.

Having a “more accurate” offset to the syntax error also helps parseException to selects a “more correct” PyParsing variable/group.  With the correct variable, its (better-selected) `.setName()` output would help the end-user to be able to deduce their (or your) errors … quicker.

Then parseException would output that new `.setName()` text string from the Python assignment containing your PyParsing logic (ParserElement) in question.

## Example Python

Here is an example of outputting a simplified EBNF in event of a `parseException`:

```py
uri = Literal('file:///') | Literal('https://')
uri.setName("""[
   https://
   | file:///
]"""
)
…

my_filepath = Optional(uri) - Optional(directory) - full_filename
my_filepath.setName('[ <uri> ] [ <directory-path> ] <full-filename>')

ls_command = Suppress(Literal('ls')) - my_filepath
ls_command.setName('ls <filepath>')
```

### Usual Output

instead seeing a very long ouput for a default but seemingly cryptic at `parseException` time:

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{Suppress('ls') + {Optional( …
```

### Readable Output

the new output would now be

```
'ls <filepath>'
```

or

```
[ <uri> ] [ <directory-path> ] <full-filename>
```

or

```
[
   https://
   | file:///
]
```

depending on where they broke your parser logic.

## Summary

With the `.setName()`/minus-operator duo, I have rarely used PyParsing debugger overhead, if at all.

Of course, the more complex your logic grows, is that good time to start adding `.setName()` to each impacted assignment.

The meantime to resolution of parseException grows shorter with each .setName added … not only for you, the developer of PyParsing logics, but immediately for your end-users.

There is one project that have over 4,000 logics written in PyParsing for `named.conf` configuration file for ISC Bind9 DNS server in [bind9_parser](https://github.com/egberts/bind9_parser). Bind9_parse made excellent uses of this duo.

Easier decipherment of parse errors by end-users of bind9_parser is kinda important.