# How to know which pyparsing ParserElement created which ParseResults?

Tags: python, pyparsing

### The problem

I have a bunch of `Group`-ed expressions like these, all of which contribute to the same grammar:

```py
first_and_operator = Group(Char('ab')('first') + Char('+-')('operator'))
full_expression = Group(first_and_operator + Char('cd')('second'))
```

```py
full_expression.parse_string('a + d', parse_all = True)
```

This, for instance, outputs the following results:

```py
ParseResults([
  ParseResults([
    # How to know that this is first_and_operator's results?
    ParseResults(['a', '+'], {'first': 'a', 'operator': '+'}),  
    'd'
  ], {'second': 'd'})
], {})
```

The innermost have the following attributes, none of which helps figuring out the original expression (these are also undocumented; there's not one mention of `modal` or `all_names` in [this whole page](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html)):

```py
[
  attr_value for attr in dir(results)
  if not attr.startswith('__')
  and not callable(attr_value := getattr(results, attr))
]
```

```py
[
  ('_all_names', set()), ('_modal', True), ('_name', 'first'),
  ('_null_values', (None, [], ())), ('_parent', None),
  ('_tokdict', {...: ...}), ('_toklist', ['a', '+']),
  ('first', 'a'), ('operator', '+')
]
```

If I'm passed an arbitrary `ParseResults` object, how do I know which expression created it?

### Things to consider and what I tried

As you may have noticed, the nested `ParseResults` object is one level deeper than needed, since `full_expression` is also a `Group`. I have [an `Expand` class](https://gist.github.com/InSyncWithFoo/6804f7e07b6363f60d3d5fcafbdd4316) that does the exact opposite (code omitted here for brevity) which may be used in a parent expression to flatten the results.

This example is simplified a lot, but in reality the equivalent of `'c'` and such are also (possibly nested) `ParseResults` objects. To handle each of these elements correctly, I need to know the type of the expression that generated it in the first place.

```py
expression_list = Expand(full_expression) + (',' + Expand(full_expression))[1, ...]
```

```py
expression_list.parse_string('a + c, a - d, b + d', parse_all = True)
```

```py
ParseResults([
  ParseResults(['a', '+'], {'first': 'a', 'operator': '+'}),
  'c', ',',
  ParseResults(['a', '-'], {'first': 'a', 'operator': '-'}),
  'd', ',',
  ParseResults(['b', '+'], {'first': 'b', 'operator': '+'}),
  'd'
], {})
```

`Expand` is a generic subclass of `TokenConverter`. This means the object passed to `Expand.postParse()` *must* be an actual `ParseResults`, or at least have the same interface of one (iterability, subscriptability, methods, etc.).

I have thought about using `.add_parse_action()` to convert that `ParseResults` into a subclass instance like this, but I am not even sure that this is the intended arguments. The parameters are also undocumented, [not type hinted](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/fad68f40a12d969344d7529bab7639d40d057ce7/pyparsing/results.py#L148) and [the code](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/fad68f40a12d969344d7529bab7639d40d057ce7/pyparsing/results.py#L171) is confusing to read.

```py
class TypedParseResults(ParseResults):
  __slots__ = ('type',)

  def __init__(self, *args, result_type: str, **kwargs):
    self.type = result_type
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

@first_and_operator.add_parse_action
def make_results_typed(results: ParseResults):
  return TypedParseResults(
    self._toklist,
    result_type = 'first_and_operator'
  )
```

This only ever raises an exception from somewhere deep down in `core.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 85, in <module>
    r = full_expression.parse_string('a + d', parse_all = True)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
  File ".../site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 895, in _parseNoCache
    ret_tokens = ParseResults(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: TypedParseResults.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'result_type'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71819618), while sounds similar, does not answer mine since it is about debugging and not runtime checking. Also, none of the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29282878) works for me, for various reasons:

- The first is incompatible with `Expand`.
- The second is ugly. Even more so with tens of expressions. In addition, it has the same problem with the third, which is explained below.

### Some context

This grammar is the origin of two parsers, one CST and one AST; the initial results need to be in some interchangeable format that can then easily be converted to both, or so I think. I would like to make the two parsers independent (no CST to AST conversion) if that is at all possible.

Each expression is a `Group`, and needs to work on its own, which means `.set_name()` (only stored at the expression, not the results) and `.set_result_name()` (might not be the same across parent expressions) doesn't work.

### Conclusion

This is particularly hard to do that I wonder if I took the wrong way. If there are better solutions to modify my existing code around, I'm willing to hear.

Comment: This looks like an infix notation parsing application. Have you looked at any of the examples that use the `infix_notation` helper (formerly named `infixNotation`)? Instead of linking to the actual parsing element, the approach is to wrap the parsed results in an object that performs the desired task.

Comment: The modal and all_names attributes are not intended to be externally used. I'll rename them with leading underscores in the next minor release.

Comment: @PaulMcG I'm not actually parsing mathematical expressions. [The actual grammar](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#grammar) is about CSS selectors. The file currently looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/InSyncWithFoo/cadaebf75b3d931eddf5b3cb99386b3a)

Comment: Regarding the wrapping, as I said, that wrapper object would need to be, or at least look like, a real `ParseResults`. Otherwise, `Expand` won't be able to handle it.